AWS Cognito - SSO - Retrieve original user
I have an application using AWS Cognito for authentication. Users can log in either via:

Cognito username/password.
External SSO provider (SAML).

Each user has a unique email that is consistent across both the Cognito and SSO logins.
Scenario:

A user registers with an email and password in Cognito, creating a user entry with a unique sub.
The same user later logs in through an SSO provider, which creates a new user entry in the user pool with a different sub.

Constraints:

Access Token Only: My application uses the access token for API authentication.
Unmodifiable Access Token: The sub in the access token cannot be changed via Pre Token Generation Lambda.

What I’ve Tried:

AdminLinkProviderForUser: Linked the SSO user to the original user, but this does not enable consistent access using the original user’s sub.
Custom Logic: Implemented logic to identify SSO logins and fetch the original sub using the user's email, but it adds complexity and potential performance overhead: Frequent use of ListUsers for every login can introduce latency and cost issues as the user base grows.

The Problem:
The access token's sub corresponds to the SSO user’s sub, causing inconsistencies in user identification across different login methods. I need a way to consistently use the original user's sub in the access token.
Question:
Is there a way to retrieve the original user's sub in the access token when logging in with an SSO provider, using Cognito’s features? Alternatively, is there a more straightforward approach to handle this scenario without sacrificing performance?
Thank you,
